# Including vendor in repo with subproject issues

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I'm stuck in irritating scenario where i'm forced to include the vendor folder in a repository because the deployment server cannot be modified until next year to run `composer install` after every deployment (i know right...)

However my issue is that some packages are being added as "subprojects" so the files are never actually added to the repo.

For example say I want to include `psr/log` in my repo then when I `git push`, the `vendor/psr/log` folder becomes *a file instead* with the contents `Subproject commit 5628725d0e4d687e29575eb41f9d5ee7de33a84c`

Is there any way to prevent this, I know this is a little weird but it's the scenario I'm stuck in so I'm wondering if anyone has been able to prevent this subproject stuff from happening so that I can actually upload all the files for a particular package to our repo.

I can't find any helpful information as this isn't your ideal scenario.

Comment: How have you installed the dependencies as submodules? I just did a very quick check installing `psr/log@^1.1` and it's all just files that I can commit

Comment: I found my solution, it was weird. (also no I didn't explicitly request that they be submodules, i was just requiring a package that also required psr/log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried everything in [composer's guide](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md) for this kind of thing and everything else I could think of, none of it worked.

I tried all the changes mentioned above and each time I would delete the .lock (it only had 1 package, don't hate) file and the vendor folder and then `composer install`; but to my frustration, it still wouldn't let me add the package files to git.

What did work:

1. Delete `vendor` folder
2. Commit the deletion: `git commit -m "TEMP: Removed vendor folder temporarily"`
3. `composer install`
4. Suddenly all the package files are now appearing in `git status` and I'm able to add them all.
5. `git add .` > `git commit -m "FIX: Readded vendor dependencies"`
6. `git push`
7. Winning - Done

For some reason step 2 here was the most important as it finally triggered the ability to be able to see all package files in git status, instead of just the `vendor/psr/log` "file"

Comment: If anyone stumbles across this and can elaborate why step 2 was required here that would be outstanding, because the need to do that is still illogical to me and I was surprised it worked.